# How can I block people from my Minecraft world?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Every time I open my world to LAN, people join and start destroying stuff. I want to ban them, but every time I ask someone for help they can't ban them.

Comment: Are you just wanting to have a world that anyone can join, or just for specific friends?  If the latter, then you can whitelist those accounts and nobody else but those people can join the server.

Comment: Which "people"?

Comment: I 2nd @immibis, which people are you referring to? If you are opening your minecraft world up to a LAN you "should" not be open to the Internet unless you had a NAT rule (i.e. port forward) setup to send traffic to your host.

Comment: Maybe you can find something like [RealLan](http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/mapping-and-modding/minecraft-mods/1286552-1-5-2-reallan-better-lan-servers-more-commands). This mod only supports MC 1.5.2, unfortunately. Someone on reddit suggests: "Make default mode spectator/adventure mode and make yourself only OP?"

Comment: Are you playing on a school's internet? (Or some other large-scale network?) Thats the only situation I can think of where random people on your LAN would want to mess with random MC worlds unless you have some really mean siblings or something...
Why do you WANT to be open to LAN? Playing with a few specific friends? Is it random griefers or the same ones every time?

Comment: It sounds like you should just set up a server... you don't have to port forward, but it will allow you to ban people.

Comment: I'm curious about these malicious people on your "LAN" too. If you have a port open to the internet at large, that could be a sign of a larger problem than just MC griefers. OTOH, if you're just on a university dorm LAN or the like, that's a different story (and I could imagine plenty of griefers in such a situation).

Comment: just came here to +1 for the title: *block* people from *minecraft*.

Answer (score 29):

I don't believe it's possible to ban players on LAN, but you could instead set up a command block to constantly kill them:

Give yourself a command block and change it to <kbd>Repeat</kbd> and <kbd>Always Active</kbd>:

[image: Command block killing the player]

You can then set the command to `/kill <PLAYER>`, and it should repeatedly kill them, making them unable to do anything.

If your chat gets spammed with `[@: Killed Player]` from this, turn off the `commandBlockOutput` gamerule:

```
/gamerule commandBlockOutput false
```

Comment: Violence is the answer.

Comment: What about `/kill @a[name=!<Player>]`

Comment: @RudolfL.Jelínek I'm guessing they want to ban certain people and still have friends play on LAN, rather than banning everyone but themself.

Comment: @colorfusion So what about using scoreboards to select "friends" and "non-friends", which will be killed?

Comment: @RudolfL.Jelínek A system using scoreboards could work, but I don't see a significant reason for the added complexity in this instance. A command block per banned player should be fine IMO; OP's just playing LAN and wanting to get rid of a few troublemakers, not running a large server.

Comment: @colorfusion We don't yet know if random players, or the same ones keep joining in. That's the problem, I guess - making a command block for each player..

Comment: The problem with this is there are minecraft clients that allow you to play as any player (but not in multiplayer) and they can constantly change names.

Comment: +1 I joined this community just to upvote the answer. Truly amazing.

Comment: Giving the tag "friend" to allowed player and just doing /kill @a[tag=!friend] would make killing non friends easy
same works for a blacklist. just change tag to "notfriend" and kill to /kill @a[tag=notfriend]
this way banning is as easy as just tagging the player as not a friend

Answer (score 10):

You could set up a whitelist on the server. It's a bit more work than just banning those who do harm, but it means that you have full control in who's allowed to join your server. Hopefully keeping those griefers at bay.

For this to work you need to have created your LAN world first, and then exit the game. After you've done that, you can [check the wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands/whitelist) for the whitelist commands.

In short. To enable the whitelist just write `/whitelist on` in the chat, and then `/whitelist add <username>` to allow players to join.

Note that I haven't tried this for a LAN server, but it should be just the same as for a dedicated one.

Comment: Agreed. Your server, LAN or otherwise, should always have a whitelist (not a blacklist, it's impossible to ban everyone bad). That way you always know who has create permissions on your server.

Comment: Currently, the link to the guide leads to a 404 Not Found error web page.

Comment: @galacticninja Thanks for the notice. I've fixed it now.

Answer (score 0):

For a LAN world (Local area network), it is impossible (except maybe with mods) to actually ban specific players. I would do a command string something like this, where it kills all players instantly except the people you want on the world (be sure to do these commands in order). Do this command on a repeater/chain command block string for everyone you want allowed to play:

`scoreboard players tag @a[name={player name}] add good`

Example:

`scoreboard players tag @a[name=4llen] add good`

Next, once you have accounted for all players you want allowed, do the following command:

`kill @a[tag=!good]`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are talking about LAN play, Ensure that your device is not connected to the network. e.g. turn off Wi-fi.