# Is it possible to make a sword that bans a player hit by it?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm wondering if it is possible to make a sword (or other weapon or tool) that bans the player being hit from the server permanently.

I tried searching it on Google, with a few different phrases, but to no avail. I found nothing. It seems no one else in the history of ever wants to know.

Is there a chain of command blocks I could write, or some mod I could install for my server that would give this functionality?

Comment: Well, technically your answer is "yes", but only by abusing a critical bug that I will not mention here.

Comment: [Identical question for Bedrock Edition](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/384049/185203)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In Minecraft Java is there a plug-in to give command blocks level 4](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/404997/in-minecraft-java-is-there-a-plug-in-to-give-command-blocks-level-4)

Comment: @pppery Shouldn't the duplicate closure be the other way around? [That other question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/404997/4797) was posted just yesterday and has a negative score.

Comment: When casting duplicate votes I prefer to dupe in the direction of the better answer. But I guess I have no objection to doing it the other way and then merging.

Answer (score 5):

## No

The `/ban` command, which would be used to ban people on a server, cannot be used in command blocks or any other means of automatically running commands.

You can, however, use command blocks to emulate the effect of banning a player, see [How can I block people from my Minecraft world?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/288347/185203) for details.

Comment: Can the Ban command be used by mods?

Comment: Presumably one could write a mod to do this, however if the question were asking for a mod if would be off-topic as a software recommendation, so I answered vanilla-only.