# Is there a plug-in to give command blocks level 4?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-java-edition-server

There are different levels of permission for commands, for example, if you have OP, you can run `/stop`, `/kick`, and `/ban`, but in a command block you can’t.

How would you be able to change this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to make a sword that bans a player hit by it?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/355508/is-it-possible-to-make-a-sword-that-bans-a-player-hit-by-it)

Comment: Actually, the answer over there is outdated and the question is a much more narrow case. I would suggest closing it as a duplicate of this one, but it's also not quite the same, because it asks for more (trigger something on hit). (I wish there was a "vote to not close" feature.)

Comment: Apparently something vaguely similar is possible from reviews, but it needs multiple people: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/125/353011

Comment: I tried to close the other way, and was told to close this way because this question is the newer one. You cant have it both ways ...

Comment: @FabianRöling The [other question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/355508/4797) is four years older and has a lot more upvotes than this one, which is only three days old and has a negative score. If one of these questions is a duplicate, it should be this one, and an updated answer should be added to the older question. If there's no duplicate, then we should just leave both questions open.

Answer (score 5):

For datapacks, you can set `function-permission-level` in `server.properties` on a dedicated server. For Singleplayer or command blocks, there is no way.